# Validate username entered and user logged in are same django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

User is Logged in and fills the form.
user enters the username in a form.
If the entered username doesn't match with username of logged in user raise error

forms.py

```
class iffc_one(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(iffc_one, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        fieldentered_username = self.cleaned_data['current_user']
        if self.user != fieldentered_username:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid user')

     class Meta:
        model = bookings_modelform
```

models.py

```
class bookings_modelform(models.Model):
    current_user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What am I doing wrong here!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It needs to raise an error if self.user != fieldentered_username. It's raising an error  even when they match each other

Comment: please provide the code where you initialize the model form. you must pass, in your case, the request.user.username as a kwarg called `user` to match to the username provided in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to validate it， You just need get logged user information from request.user and put it into yourcmodel.

```
bookings_model.current_user = request.user.username
```

Comment: I am trying to validate the form, where the user enters the username.

Comment: In this context，the username should not be entered by user, it should be got from request.user

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where does this code go into. I am getting an error if I entered it in models.py

Comment: in the action view because just view has request param input